# Induction on a triangular equality related problem

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I have to prove $|a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n|\leq |a_1|+|a_2|+\dots+|a_n|$
For $n$ numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n,\dots$.

How can I start this problem?

I used this so far (triangular equality set up or rather an attempt)

$$
\begin{align}
(|a_1|+\dots+(|a_n|)^2 & = (a_1+\dots+a_n)(a_1+\dots+a_n) \\[8pt]
& =a_1^2+\dots+2a_1a_n+\dots+a_n^2 \\[8pt]
& \leq |a_1^2|+\dots+2|a_1||a_n|+\dots+|a_n^2| \\[8pt]
& \leq(|a_1|+\dots+|a_n|)^2
\end{align}
$$

Then remove the squares..

Comment: Do you mean $|a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}|$ for the left side?

Comment: Much too complicated. $\lvert a + b + c\rvert \leqslant \lvert a \rvert + \lvert b+c\rvert$. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

First we show, $|a_1 + a_2| \le |a_1| + |a_2|$ by squaring and using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Then we show rest inductively.

let $b = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots  + a_n$, then 
 $|a_1 + a_2 + \cdots  + a_n + a_{n+1}| =|b + a_{n+1}| \le |b| + |a_{n+1}| \le |a_1| + |a_2| + \dots + |a_n| + |a_{n+1}|$